# Neutron - Invalid input for operation: physical_network 'physnet_em1' unknown for VLAN provider network

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-neutron

I installed Openstack using Devstack on a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu 18.04. I am trying to create a provider network with the following command:

```
neutron net-create mgmt --provider:network_type=vlan --provider:physical_network=physnet_em1 --provider:segmentation_id=500 --shared
```

This command returns the following error:

```
neutronclient.common.exceptions.BadRequest: Invalid input for operation:
physical_network 'physnet_em1' unknown for VLAN provider network.
Neutron server returns request_ids: ['req-7a0bfe13-b4c3-4408-bc60-8d36e8bc3f9a']
```

I would like to know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should use the openstack-client commands like `openstack network create ...`, because the client-commands of the single libraries, like your `neutron net-create`, are deprecated. There are some really special cases, which are only possible with the client-library of the single components, but the most is covered by the openstack-client. Unfortunately there are often used the old commands in documentations, because many documents are not up-to-date.
2. To avoid the error you had, you only need to remove the `--provider:physical_network=physnet_em1` and `--provider:segmentation_id=500` from your command. The physical network and vlan-range should be defined within the `ml2_conf.ini` of the neutron-server, like this for example:

   ```
   [ml2]
   type_drivers = flat,vlan,vxlan
   ...

   [ml2_type_vlan]
   network_vlan_ranges = physnet_em1:171:280
   ...
   ```

   So with `neutron net-create mgmt --provider:network_type=vlan --shared` it works in my test-deployment (at least there in no error in the terminal, not tested the network-connectioin now). The openstack-command for this task would be `openstack network create --provider-network-type vlan mgmt --share --external`.
3. Normally, as far as I know, for the provider network a `flat` network-type is used instead of `vlan`, because the provider-network should normally not directly connected to any VM. The other non-provider networks can be vlan or vxlan and then connected with a neutron-router to the provider-network. An openstack-command for this could be: `openstack network create --provider-network-type flat --provider-physical-network physnet_em1 mgmt --share --external`. For flat-networks you have the possibility to define a `provider-physical-network` via command-line.
   In some documentations like this: https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-ubuntu/launch-instance-networks-provider.html they also use a `flat`-network as provider-network-type.

Comment: Thank you, @Tobias . Can you tell what do these numbers (171:280) represent after the `physnet_em1`?

Comment: @DaltonCézane Yeah, sorry. I should had written this in the below the example. These numbers are the vlan range you give openstack as available range. In this example-case it would use the vlan-tags from 171 until 280 for the tagging of all created vlan-networks in your openstack-deployment. So it also defines a limitation. You can only create an amount of networks, like this range size allows.

Comment: So you can free decide in this config-file, which range do you want, as long as the values are in the allowed vlan-range of 0-4095.

Comment: Thank you, @Tobias . I had configured without this range and it did not work. As I rebooted the machine, when I tested again, it worked. This indicates that the vlan range is not mandatory.

Comment: @DaltonCézane Thanks for the feedback. I only used the vlan-type one or two times, before I switched to vxlan networks, so I never tested it without the range. ;)